# Openshift - rhc setup - in 'require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to install the Openshift client tools using the procedure available [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html).

At the step requiring to perform `rhc set-up`, I get the following error message:

[image]

I am on a Windows 10 64 bit laptop. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the output as text please? It's quite hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ruby2.2.0. I had similar problems and I downgraded ruby to 1.9.3 as from the tutorial https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#client-tools and it worked at least on my windows 7 64 machine.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am including the link to download 1.9.3: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives

Answer (score 1):

Somebody on SO  even recently had a problem with Ruby 1.9.3.  Try that or Ruby 2.0