# rhc setup command giving error

Tags: ruby, openshift

I am setting up openshift client tools as described here : https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html but i am getting an error on the command "rhc setup" . `Error : cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)`   I have searched for it and found solution on stackoverflow:

Solution link : [rhc setup gives error `no such file dl/import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import)

I have updated net-ssh to 2.9.3.beta1 but i am still getting this error . Full stack trace is given below .

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:77:in `<class:Wizard>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:7:in `<module:RHC>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:2:in `<module:Commands>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:189:in `block in load'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: There is already similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463357/openshift-rhc-setup-in-require-cannot-load-such-file/34470362#34470362

Answer (score 1):

By your stack trace you are on Ruby 2.2. Down grade to 1.9.3 or 2.2.0.